# Whitney's topology

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, differential-topology

Receive a cordial greeting, I am looking for a book or article on Whitney's topology, I will begin to do my degree thesis and I am interested in this topic, I appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: Hirsch has a good section on it. I think this guys notes are also pretty good: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ruiloja/Math519/compaan.pdf

Comment: Excuse me @User203940,  
Hirsh's book is differential topology

Comment: It is not entirely on Whitney topologies but it has a section on it. I'm not sure what you're looking for without more details.

Comment: @User203940 My director told me to research an article or book about what a Whitney topology is and its consequences.

Comment: Have you tried Googling? Did it help?